# request validation 404 error with laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with the validation rules with laravel 8.

there is a bug, when I put several rules (in table) on a field, I get a 404 error.

doesn't work:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'type' => [
            'required',
            'regex:/^(firstname|lastname|custom)$/i'
        ]
    ];
}
```

works:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your validation rules can cause a 404 error, since 404 is "page not found" ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
it is however the case, if I replace the line type by 'type' => 'required', it works. If I put an array of rules for the type field, I have a 404

Comment: Does the url change? I personally define multiple rules with `|` instead of an array. `=> 'required|regex:/^(firstname|lastname|custom)$/i'` .

Comment: URL doesn't change. I make API.
Me too but i have this error if i don't use array:
ErrorException: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in file ...Concerns\ValidatesAttributes.php on line 1413.

Comment: Just an FYI on the array syntax, the [docs say](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex) - *When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to specify your validation rules using an array instead of using | delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a | character.*

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you. I use array but i have a 404 error. i don't know why..

Comment: 404 error comes when a rule fails.

Comment: I found an answer on a forum but I do not understand why.
in the request in postman I must add in the header X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest.
why ?